# What is the most efficient way to handle multiple players key inputs in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm programming a game with pygame and was wandering what is the best way to handle multiple players key inputs in it, like in a pong game where you can handle key inputs from the 'w, s' keys for one player and the arrow keys for the other.

The way I'm doing it now is by using a variable called 'control_type' in my Player class that is assigned when each player is initialized. Then inside the Player class I check if the variable is equal to 'wasd' or 'arrows' and then check the key inputs accordingly. It works, but sometimes it seems to lag and skip some frames. Is this a good way to do it or is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: Are you able to share a [mcve]? That will help us understand your approach. Are you handling events in multiple places, because that sounds sub-optimal.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, but if you say

> but sometimes it seems to lag and skip some frames

remember one thing (because that's a common mistake):

Only ever call `pygame.event.get()` once per frame. If a key is pressed and the event is added to the queue, and you call `pygame.event.get()` and don't handle that event, it is lost, and another call to `pygame.event.get()` will not recieve it.

A common pattern I use is to store all events of a frame in a list, and use that list in multiple places to check for events that the current piece of code is interested in. When using the `Sprite` class, you can simple pass that list to your `Group` to pass it down to the sprites.

Simplified example:

```
...
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for e in events:
        ... handle "global" events like QUIT

    sprites.update(events) # pass events to all sprites
```

Then in a sprite class

```
class Foo(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   ...
   def update(self, events):
       for e in events:
           ... handle other events
```

Another thing to note: in a game like Pong, where you move by holding a key, you're probably not interested in the individual key events, but rather the current state of the key (is it pressed or not?). So you want to call `pygame.key.get_pressed()` to get the state of the keyboard. Calling `pygame.key.get_pressed()` multiple times is fine.

Another simplified pseudo example:

```
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, up_key, down_key, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = ...
        self.rect = ...
        self.up_key = up_key
        self.down_key = down_key

    def update(self):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[self.up_key]:  self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)
        if pressed[self.up_down]: self.rect.move_ip(0,  1)
```

and initialize multiple players like:

```
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
Player(p1, pygame.K_w, pygame.K_s, sprites)
Player(p2, pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN, sprites)
```

Comment: Seems like a more optimal way to do it. I will try doing it when I start a new project, this one was just to test how to implement multiple players input. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A method I've used successfully is whenever a call to pygame.event.get() is made, if the event pulled is needed elsewhere, just put it back on the queue. For example

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            handle_up()
        # Check for all your other relevant keys...

        elif event.key == pygame.K_w: # Or any key you need elsewhere
            pygame.event.post(event) # Put it back on the queue
```

You'll need to be careful about this as putting too many things back on the queue can cause the queue to fill up. But if everything you put back on the queue is definitely going to be used elsewhere, then you're good.